# Delphi - Use a string variable's name in assignfile()

Tags: file, delphi, variables, assign

Is it possible to use a variable in the assignfile command?

Eg.

```
f : Textfile ;
sFile : string ;  {contains 'MyFile.txt' as content}

...

cFileDir = 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Data Engine\Data\Country' ;

...

Assignfile(f, cFileDir + '\' + sFile) ;

...
```

I appreciate your help very much. if it's unclear I'll edit the question to add more details.

Comment: I don't understand why you ask the question. It would have taken you less time to simply try it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to use a variable in the `AssignFile` command?

Yes.

1. The second parameter of [`AssignFile`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.AssignFile) has type `string`.
2. The expression `cFileDir + '\' + sFile` has type `string`.

FWIW, `AssignFile` is known as a *function* rather than a *command*. Getting on top of terminology like this will help you learn the language more effectively.

Comment: Thanks, I did IT in school, but it's been years since then and I only recently started touching the language again.  I'll be sure to brush up on my terminology.